# How can solve integral involving Hermite polynomials?

Tags: numerical-integration

How can solve integral involving Hermite polynomials with following form?

```
Nn = Sqrt[Sqrt[\[Beta]]/((2^n)*(n!)*Sqrt[Pi])];
\[Psi]n = 
  Nn*Exp[-((\[Beta]*(((1/\[Gamma])*Log[1 + \[Gamma]*x])^2) + 
       Log[1 + \[Gamma]*x])/2)]*
   HermiteH[n, (Sqrt[\[Beta]]/\[Gamma])*Log[1 + \[Gamma]*x]];

norm = Simplify[\[Psi]n*
    Conjugate[\[Psi]n], {Element[{x, \[Gamma], \[Beta], n}, Reals], 
    x \[GreaterSlantEqual] 0, \[Gamma] \[GreaterSlantEqual] 
     0, \[Beta] \[GreaterSlantEqual] 0, n \[GreaterSlantEqual] 0}];
f = ((D[norm, n])^2)/(norm);


Z = 
     Simplify[Integrate[
       f, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}], {Element[{x, \[Gamma], \[Beta], n}, 
        Reals], x \[GreaterSlantEqual] 0, \[Gamma] \[GreaterSlantEqual] 
        0, \[Beta] \[GreaterSlantEqual] 0, n \[GreaterSlantEqual] 0}]
```

Comment: You should check the reference page for `Integrate`. There are several things amiss here. But even so, it might just be something `Integrate` cannot handle symbolically.

Comment: In general, Mathematica cannot integrate by substitutions, $$\text{ Integrate  }    a(x ) HermiteH[n, f(Log[x])]  dx$$  never will be processed. You have  to substitute an y for x such that $$ \text{H}(n,y) dy $$ has a chance to be integrated.

Comment: Shouldn't `n` be an element of the Nonegative integers? `Hermite[n,t]` is only defined for non-negative integer `n`. And I'm not really sure what it would mean to take the derivative w.r.t `n` of a Hermite polynomial. The closest thing to a derivative w.r.t `n` I could think of would be `HermiteH[n,t]-HermiteH[n-1,t]` for `n>=1` since it only admits integer `n`